# Laravel/Livewire display data on table if today is between 2 dates

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to populate my table with data if today is between posting date and closing date.

```
public function mount(Career $career)
    {
        $this->today = Carbon::now();
        $this->posting = Carbon::parse($career->posting_date);
        $this->closing = Carbon::parse($career->closing_date);
        $this->career = Career::where($this->posting, '<=', $this->today) ->where($this->closing, '<=', $this->today)->get();
        $this->sortBy            = 'id';
        $this->sortDirection     = 'asc';
        $this->perPage           = 100;
        $this->paginationOptions = config('project.pagination.options');
        $this->orderable         = (new Career())->orderable;
        
    }
```

I'm getting this error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2022-05-06 01:10:12' in 'where clause'

also if I try to display `$today`, `$posting` and `$closing` on my blade, they all show date today.

Comment: You're passing a data as a column name, you need to specify the column name. I don't know what it is but read the documentation for the where clause in your sql and find out which positional parameters go where

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Can you give me a hint on how to do it? thank you

Comment: I don't know larvel or how you prepare and pass sql stamens but that sql error is very descriptive. Maybe if you said exactly which line was causing the error I could go from there

Comment: I fixed the error using this line `$this->career = Career::where('posting_date', '<=', $this->today) ->where('closing_date', '>=', $this->today)->get();` but now I have another error saying `Cannot assign Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection to property App\Http\Livewire\Career\Vacant::$career of type App\Models\Career`

Comment: show us the Vacant livewire component

Comment: solved it. posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by editing my render and putting >whereDate.

```
public function render()
{   
    $query = Career::advancedFilter([
        's'               => $this->search ?: null,
        'order_column'    => $this->sortBy,
        'order_direction' => $this->sortDirection,])
        ->whereDate('posting_date', '<=', Carbon::now())
        ->whereDate('closing_date', '>=', Carbon::now());

    $careers = $query->paginate($this->perPage);

    return view('livewire.career.vacant', compact('careers', 'query'));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must enter a column name in your query and you cannot enter a date in the column name field

```
$this->career = Career::where('column_name', '<=', $this->today) ->where('column_name', '<=', $this->today)->get();
```